# Get Variables From Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 arrays like this.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 4
)
Array
(
    [id] => 6
)
Array
(
    [id] => 7
)
```

What I would like to do is make a variable called `$id` that prints the id values as a string 4,6,7.  How would I accomplish this?

Comment: `echo $myArray1['id'], ',', $myArray2['id'], ',', $myArray3['id'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have those three arrays with the element `"your_key"` each,In first put `arrays` in some variable then you can simply concatenate the values using '`.`' in php:

```
$arr1=Array
(
    ['id'] => 4
)
$arr2=Array
(
    ['id'] => 6
)
$arr3=Array
(
    ['id'] => 7
)

$key = "id";
$id = $arr1[$key] . "," . $arr2[$key] . "," . $arr3[$key];
echo $id;
```

**Edit:** You can use the same approach in a loop:

```
$id = "";
$key = "id";

foreach($results as $result) {
    $id .= $result[$key] . ",";
}

$id = rtrim($id, ",");

echo $id;
```

Comment: You're missing the $ before array1, array2, and array3 variables.  Tried editing, but it wasn't enough characters to change :)

Comment: What is my arrays don't have an array name?  They are listed exactly as I posted above.

Comment: How / why are your arrays stored without a name?

Comment: I get the arrays in this way, from a mysql query:

`$results = $mysqli->query(Whatever the query is);`

Then: `foreach ($results as $result) {
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';}`

That gives me the result I pasted above.

Comment: @Wes you can use a `foreach` like this: `foreach (array[id] as arr){$var .= $arr;}`

Comment: @Wes Have a look at my edit, the approach is still perfectly valid if you use it in your loop.

Comment: @TimoSta looks like we posted that at the same time :P Yours looks a little cleaner with the rtrim

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, this seems like the way you should go

```
$id = '';
$i=0;
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
$len = count($results);
foreach($results as $result) {
    $id .= $result['id'];
    $i++;
    if($i < $len) {
        $id .= ',';
    }
}
```